# Frequency Compensation Necessary for a Buck Converter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, frequency, buck, stability

I've been tinkering with switch mode power supplies recently and it seems there are various types of buck controller IC's some with a 'COMP' pin for frequency compensation and some without, and I was wondering what the major trade offs are to having or not having this input? I know that well designed frequency compensation can control your feedback gain and stability so does that mean that the chips without that pin are inherently unstable?

For example two chips I am looking at are the [TPS54531](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54531.pdf) from TI and the [MC34063A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf). The MC34063 is appealing because it's cheap and a buck converter design with an external switch for high amperage seems fairly straight forward. The TPS54531 requires frequency compensation which is a bit more complicated and the chip appears to be much more expensive.

Are there chips that are cheap that allow for frequency compensation or is it something that I don't even need to worry about?

Edit: I also found this application note for the MC34063A useful: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva252b/slva252b.pdf

Comment: The MC34063 is actually not from TI but from Onsemi. Ideally you'd also make the IC numbers links to the datasheets.

Comment: Woops sorry about that, I've been reading too many datasheets. Give me a sec and I'll link both.

Comment: I don't think you should worry too much about the freq. comp. If the voltage regulation loop needs it is either on the chip or external (like for the TPS54531). Having it external sometimes allows the user to tweak it to compromise stability against transient behavior (make loop faster but could be more unstable). But usually you should just use the recommended components, for the TPS54531 I could not see the network discussed in the datasheet so probably it should be as suggested in the datasheet and not be changed. So indeed: do not worry about it too much.

Comment: I see now how the MC34063 confusion started, I think it was originally a TI product and Onsemi made a clone/replacement part.

Comment: Some [relevant reading](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/AN149fa.pdf).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah that's what had me mixed up. I have the correct datasheets linked now, thanks. Alright, so the freq. comp. pin is just for more fine tuned performance at the risk of instability, not necessarily a requirement for a stable buck converter?

Comment: Well, if the chip needs those 2 caps and a resistor, you cannot leave them out, if you do the circuit will become unstable. All buck converters have a loop. All these loops must be stable (obviously). To make the loop stable there might be an **external** frequency compensation network needed (example: TPS54531) or not (example: MC34063 and many others). It is similar to opamps, some need an external freq comp. capacitor, others don't. Some opamps only need it for unity-gain, others are unity-gain stable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for the article, it was a good read. I think TI has something similar that's a bit more math heavy.

Bimpelrekkie right, I follow now. So the ones that don't have the pin are stable but might not give the best performance necessarily but the IC's with the pin require the external compensator which gives more flexibility but also more room for problems.

Comment: One other point to keep in mind: you can cheat a bit. Faster reaction in the regulator lets you use a smaller filter cap. If you're building a one-off, you can cheat a bit on the design: over-compensate the regulator, and use a bigger filter cap to make up the difference. If you're doing huge production, then you get into the game of reducing compensation to the minimum, so you can also minimize the filter cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a compensation pin exists lets you tailor your compensator to meet certain design goals: a specific crossover frequency (the point at which the loop-gain magnitude crosses the 0-dB axis), phase and gain margins. You know that the frequency response of a switching converter is affected by parasitic elements like \$r_C\$ the capacitor equivalent series resistance (ESR) which introduces a zero for instance. So when then the compensation is internal (like with a 3-pin linear regulator for instance), then you may have conditions on these stray elements for which the stability is ensured or not. It is your role then to pick the right passive component and make sure its parasitics match the manufacturer recommendations.

On the other hand, if the comp pin is available, then you can choose the compensation strategy to neutralize the effects of the parasitics knowing that they will move between known boundaries during the converter lifetime. You can also tailor the transient response you can accept (fast response with overshoot then moderate phase margin, sluggish response but 0 overshoot with higher phase margin) by selecting where to place poles and zeros.

A lot of ICs integrate operational transconductance amplifiers (OTAs) for design reasons (small die area etc.) but I don't like them especially if you are about to implement a type-3 compensator (1 pole at origin, 2 zeros and 2 poles). As highlighted [here](http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf), you see that depending on the division ratio between \$V_{out}\$ and \$V_{ref}\$ you are limited in spreading one of the pole/zero pair and cannot boost the phase as much as you would like to. Also, in an OTA, the transconductance \$g_m\$ enters the picture as well as the resistive ratio fixing \$V_{out}\$.

Regarding the MC34063, it is a hysteretic controller inherently instable and does not need to be compensated. It can be extremely noisy as the bunch recurrence can enter the audible range at high peak currents. I think it has been released by MOT after Signetics introduced the µA78S40: yes, some years ago : )

Comment: Nice answer, that helped clear up the confusion I was having with regards to the chips that don't have the compensation pin. Thanks for the heads up on the MC34063, I'm realizing that I may just need to go with a newer/more advanced chip to get a more stable output.

Comment: Glad if I could help!